# Drying hands after leaving cemetery

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, cemetery-grave

I understand that we are supposed to let our hands air-dry after washing them (when leaving a cemetery).  Can we blow dry them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.jewishpress.com/printArticle.cfm?contentid=41065

Per this link, the whole idea of not drying hands when leaving a cemetery is a "Minhag Taus" and there would not be any problem with air drying them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and should probably be a comment: The premise of the question is according to those who say that it is a minhag...

Comment: +1 comment to yydl.  Firstly if I'm not mistaken, the hand-washing is tuma related (but because now we're all considered tamea... then it might be a minhag)